# Java Scanner nextLong

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Stackoverflow, hello.
I have problem understanding the output to this piece of code

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String context = "0100 55 3L 62D 127 6F (int)7";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(context);
    while(s.hasNextLong()) {
        System.out.print(s.nextLong() + ",");
    }
}
```

The output is `100,55,`
but I don't understand why `127` wasn't included to the output? I mean why the output isn't like `100,55,127,` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Scanner#nextLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong%28%29) doesn't parse `Long` literals, it parses numbers as longs, so it fails to find one at `3L` and exits the loop, ie. [`hasNextLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLong%28%29) returns `false`.

Note the javadoc

> Scans the next token of the input as a long.

In this case the next token is `3L` and that doesn't parse to a `Long`. Try it

```
Long.parseLong("3L");
```

will give you a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the javadoc api: Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a long value in the default radix using the nextLong method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `3L 62D`, try to modify your input as:

```
String context = "0100 55 127 3L 62D  6F (int)7";
```

Than output will be : 100, 55, 127